# How to retrieve data from Firebase database after passing currentUserID

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

This is my firebase database and table:

[image: firebase database and table].

I want to retrieve data from table 'active' by using userID. I tried it like this in my **service.ts** file.

```
getCurrentUserData(userID){
    return new Observable(obs => {
      this.db.list('/active')
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe(res => {
         console.log(res)
     })
   });
}
```

assume current userID `userID = "oiV0Q09hLbWv0nhFUeFd94aWF3f1"` and that **table has so many another UserID also**.I want to get current user details only.Using that code i receive all data in table.How can get only current user data using UserID.How can i edit my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the angulafire2 [doc](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md), I think you should do like the following. In other words, you should narrow your query in such a way the filtering is done at the level of the database itself and not on the client side.

```
 getCurrentUserData(userID){
    return new Observable(obs => {
      this.db.list('/active', ref => ref.orderByKey().equalTo('oiV0Q09hLbWv0nhFUeFd94aWF3f1'))
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe(res => {
         console.log(res)
     })
   });
}
```

Note that the angulafire2 doc gives also some explanations about Dynamic Querying.

You can also read the Firebase doc about querying, [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data), which gives more details on querying techniques.

Comment: thank you so much.Your solution work for me.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

use `filter` operator to filter out the result by id

```
 getCurrentUserData(userID){
    return new Observable(obs => {
      this.db.list('/active')
      .filter(p => p.userID === "oiV0Q09hLbWv0nhFUeFd94aWF3f1")
      .valueChanges()
      .subscribe(res => {
         console.log(res)
     })
   });
}
```

Comment: Then I get like this error   [ _this.db.list(...).valueChanges(...).filter is not a function ]